# The difference between sick and ill

Tags: usage

I feel ill or sick. Both mean the same. But when they modify a noun, do they mean the same? For example,

Sentence A: He is a sick person.

Sentence B: He is an ill person.

Do they mean the same?

I want to know the difference because 'ill' can mean 'bad' in some senses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've already said, *ill* can mean *bad* in some senses. But so can *sick*. In fact, *sick* is the more common word if you want to describe somebody in the *bad* sense. (However, *sick* can also be used as a slang term for *cool* or *awesome*.)

Context determines the meaning:

> That serial killer is one sick individual.
>   Ill intentions often result in ill deeds.

---

If you mean *physically unwell*, neither of your sentences would be normal. By adding *person*, you are implying the *bad* sense.

The best way to describe someone who is unwell, and have it be interpreted as you want, is to add the word *feeling*:

> He is feeling sick.
>   He is feeling ill.

Or:

> He isn't feeling well.

It's also common to say (in informal dialogue):

> "He isn't feeling good."

---

In terms of describing being physically unwell, *sick* and *ill* are mostly used interchangeably.

But per [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20feel%20sick%2CI%20feel%20ill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20sick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20ill%3B%2Cc0), *sick* seems to be the more common of the two words.

[image: ill or well]

Comment: Also, in a slang context, I've heard "ill" as a more positive adjective (Beastie Boys song "Time to Get Ill"). "Sick" can be used in the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jason Bassford. I can now understand from your explanation that the meaning has to be deduced from context rather than words themselves.

Comment: In British English, to 'be sick' commonly means to vomit, and what is produced can be called 'sick' (mass noun). Child: what's for dinner, Daddy? Father, jocularly: a cup of cold sick!

Comment: It's even more confusing than that: ‘to feel ill’ and ‘to feel sick’ can both refer either to general illness or to nausea, too.  Similarly, some people use ‘to be ill’ to refer to vomiting, in the same way I'd say ‘to be sick’.  So there's a shedload of ambiguity there.

Comment: Although "ill" can mean bad in _some_ situations (such as your examples), I think it's important to note that "He is ill" unambiguously means "He is not healthy".